# Does [retain] really need to be retained?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I've stumbled over that pretty useless tag today: [retain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retain)
No tag wiki information 1 follower and 454 questions tagged.

Please remove that tag, since it doesn't add any valuable information to the questions.

Answer (score 3):

The top 10 related tags fall into two main categories:

- Related to objective-c or other Apple/IOS code
- Memory management for properties (in objective-c)

And a quick [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=retain%20objective%20c) for "retain objective c" seems to confirm that retain is a *keyword* used in objective c to help manage memory, but it's only one of multiple management options (including "assign" and "copy").

So it appears that retain is **easily replaced** by a combination of a kind of [memory-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/memory-management) tag and a kind of [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) tag.  That makes this tag redundant and a good burnination target.