# This tag is such a [software-tools]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [SO Close Vote Reviewers (warning, link contains mild profanity)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=24296262#24296262) chatroom has been taking on the blatantly off topic [software-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-tools) tag for a couple of days. 62 questions remain, which are broken down below.

Every question in the tag is now closed (the on-topic ones have been edited/retagged), and [30 of them](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware-tools%5D+score%3A..0+closed%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ano+is%3Aquestion)  are roomba eligible [waiting the 9 days for deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/200235).

<strike>However, there are a few questions in the tag that need delete votes or retagging. In particular, there are [19 questions with an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware-tools%5D+hasaccepted%3Ayes), not to mention 2 questions that [don't have an accepted answer and aren't easily roomba eligible.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsoftware-tools%5D+score%3A1..+closed%3Ayes+hasaccepted%3Ano+is%3Aquestion)</strike>

We definitely need moderator help, because there are two **locked** questions that we can't burninate:

- [Pirated software at a company?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/899699/1768232)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/5807703/1768232

Thanks @JonClements for burninating the two locked questions!

##Let's burninate it!

[image]

Comment: The locked questions have had the tag removed...

Comment: [tag:burinate-request]'s keep on going to put more and more drama for their appearance here. I certainly should try to bang my [latest question about such](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298450/does-retain-really-need-to-be-retained) in similar shape.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What can I say, [I liek kewl piktures](https://metrodetroitdad.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/kewl-cat.jpg)

Comment: @durron597 Sure, that's an impressive one ;-) ...

Comment: I did two before I remembered but is this just for 2K users whose edits don't go into the review queue?

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for volunteering to help out! To answer your question, I recommend reading this: [How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/1768232)

Comment: Since when is my room NSFW?

Comment: Woah, stackoverflow has chat rooms? How do you get in on that stuff? I've never seen them before.

Comment: @Jashaszun http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ You can find it under the top-left Stack Exchange menu, next to the "Current Community / StackOverflow"

Comment: That [`[culture]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/culture) tag on the "pirate software" post is pretty questionable as well.

Comment: @davidism You are welcome to start another burnination post... :)

Comment: The singular/plural mismatch really makes the title.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Every question that isn't roomba eligible in this tag has been deleted or retagged. On July 18th or 19th or so, the tag will be completely purged.</strike>

The last question was deleted today. The tag will be fully removed tomorrow!

Great job everyone!

Comment: Another great effort by the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room team - thanks everyone!