# Is it worth flagging "Not An Answer" for link only answers on closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, link-only-answers

I noticed this happening a lot when looking at the questions tagged with [software-tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298928/this-tag-is-such-a-software-tools) but my question is for the general case.

Stack Overflow says that an answer that doesn't work without the links in it isn't really an answer and should be flagged as "Not an Answer". That pretty much describes any answer on recommendation questions, which are quickly closed as being off topic.

Is it worth it to flag those answers on questions that have already been closed? It could make some questions with a score of zero eligible for deletion if they no longer have up voted answers but I don't want to start flagging them if, as a rule, we shouldn't bother flagging answers on closed questions.

Comment: The question is probably off topic in the first place if it's a recommendation, so just flag to close the question and let's be done with it?

Comment: @Patrice *"...on questions that have already been closed"*

Comment: @Patrice - The questions I'm talking about are already closed...though I guess that's still a vote for "don't bother with the answers".

Comment: mea culpa, I should read the question through and through before posting a comment... but... but I've been upvoted so someone did the same! In that case... that is indeed a good question... I'd still think don't bother since the question is closed... but I can see value in removing the answers as well

Comment: _but I've been upvoted so someone did the same!_ @Patrice Yeah it happens. Don't worry about it. I should probably make that more clear in my question.

Comment: @BSMP sorry for jumping the gun though. It really changes the meaning of your question (to me at least) and completely invalidates my comment :P.

Comment: Flagging creates more work for the mods. Down-vote the bad answer, especially if it has a positive score, and move on.

Comment: very closely related: [Why were these NAA flags declined for content-less link-only answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336546/839601)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, it's totally not worth it.

Spend the time you save not flagging these by working to earn 10K reputation so that you can vote to delete the question and rid us of these answers en masse. If the whole mess is actively harmful in some way, you can flag *the question* for moderator attention and ask that they expedite the removal (be clear as to the problem).

The fact that these questions tend to *attract* such answers is a big reason why they're now off-topic. You can't really blame the flies for being stuck to fly paper...

Comment: If come by through normal searching, shouldn't these still be flagged when appropriate? We certainly don't want users spending their time looking for them. But, if they stumble upon one, shouldn't it be flagged for users who can take action? Wouldn't this be better for us users to handle marking such flags as valid then letting the system delete these over time instead of them flagging these posts for you, already overly busy, mods?

Comment: @codeMagic: The point here is to not miss the forest for the trees.