# A bogus known-bad LQP audit on a rec question

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits, recommendation-questions

[This particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9005927) gives some degree of reasoning for why the linked resource should be used.

[image]

It's therefore (as I see it) *not* NAA. The proper handling in any case, per Shog, is [not to bother deleting individual answers on a rec question but to close the question and leave it severely alone for the roomba to delete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299024/4099598). This should therefore *not be an audit*: the correct handling cannot actually be tested, inefficient or wrong handling of the post is actively recommended by the audit system, and suitable courses of action are wrongly punished.

(Getting stuck for 10, 15 seconds, or however long it is, when I already know immediately **a)** why I failed the audit and **b)** that the failure is wrong, hasty, and misguided and that I was in fact correct just adds that much more frustration to my annoyance. It's not like the extra time will actually enable me to review my choices, strictly speaking: I can't see the post anymore!)

Comment: I'm wondering if it could have anything to do with it being deleted by a mod.

Comment: @TinyGiant: That's one of the ways audits are generated: if there's an active NAA or VLQ flag on there when a mod deletes it ... even if they delete it for a different reason ... it's an audit case.