# Closure, but not answer deletion, for "ruby style guide" question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

The closed question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616037/ruby-coding-style-guidelines , which asked for links to off-site resources, had 12 answers, all of which have been deleted, 10 of them by the same user who closed the question and on the same day.

While the closure of the question is consistent with community guidelines, the deletion of the answers seems to be overkill. The fault for them being link answers lies with the question, which was closed, rather than with the answers.

Comment: I probably bet the answers were flagged as NAA and the moderator only sees the answer and not the question, when he reviewed the flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, this looks untidy.

As usual, the solution is slightly more deletion.

#### See also: [Is it worth flagging "Not An Answer" for link only answers on closed questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299023/is-it-worth-flagging-not-an-answer-for-link-only-answers-on-closed-questions)

Comment: FWIW, I'd be far more inclined to try preserving some of these questions if googling "ruby style guide" or "ruby coding standards" didn't produce essentially the same results; when SO questions get in the way of folks searching for answers, we're not really helping.